# Create an api in api gateway to invoke a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, api-gateway

I am working on a project and trying to use API Gateway to invoke a lambda function. The lambda function is used to update a DynamoDB item. The DynamoDB table is used to keep a running count of visitors to a web page. I need to create an API to invoke the lambda function but I'm not sure how to create the API. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

General steps would be:

1. Create **AWS_PROXY** integration between API Gateway and your Lambda function. The example of this is in the AWS tutorials: [Set up Lambda proxy integrations in API Gatewa](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) and in [Tutorial: Build a REST API with HTTP proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html)
2. Add/amend **execution role** to your function allowing it to access DynamoDB. This is exemplified in the AWS tutorial: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html).
3. **Test the API**. It can be done directly in API gateway console, or using external tools such as `curl` or `Postman`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have my Lambda function working correctly. When I execute it manually from the console, I can see the count increase in DynamoDB, which is what I want it to do. When I go to API Gateway and create it, I run the test and I get a 200 status but the response is null. What do I need to do to return the same value from the Lambda function? Do I need to add path parameters? Query strings?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. In my lamdba function, I needed to change the output to a JSON object. Once I made the change, I was able to get my API working. Here is a link to the [fix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html).